# Filling xAxis for all nights in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to fill the datetime on xAxis for each night ?

I managed to do it for one night, but would like to do that for every night which is displayed. As a must, it would be nice to calculate the real sunrise and sunset and allow the display only when the scale allow to see it. Over a week, it has no sense.

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        plotBands: [{ 
        color:'rgba(156,156,156,.15)',
        from: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 13,19),
        to: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 14,5),
            label: {                            
            text: '☾',
            style : {color : '#D9B11D',
            fill : '#D9B11D',
            fontSize :'20px' },
            align: 'left',
            x: 10,y: 30
        }
    }]
```

Thanks,

Comment: There isn't a built in way to do what you want.  But, you can have as many plot bands as you want.  Preprocess your data and add and remove plot bands as necessary

Comment: That's what i'm looking for.. How should i proceed ? I'm not a keen programmer...

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Barbara,have a look here : [link]http://www.egloff.eu/apaguard-new/apaguard_graph_ruche.php?rucher=1&ruche=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can process the data for plot bands like this:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var xAxis = this.xAxis[0], 
            ex = xAxis.getExtremes(),
          start = ex.min,
          plotBands = [];


          while (start + nightLength < ex.max) {

            plotBands.push({
              from: start,
              to: start + nightLength,
              color: 'rgba(156,156,156,.15)',
              label: {
                text: '☾',
                style: {
                  color: '#D9B11D',
                  fill: '#D9B11D',
                  fontSize: '20px'
                },
                align: 'left',
                y: 30
              }
            });
            start += day;

          }
          xAxis.update({
            plotBands: plotBands
          });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/cpk59waw/

An important part of the code is the chart extremes constraint (so that there're only as much plot bands as needed):

```
 while (start + nightLength < ex.max)
```

I implemented very simplified case here. The assumptions are that the night has a constant length and the sunrise always happens on the same time.

If you want to have real values for sunrise and sunset you should find some data source for it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great script.
Meanwhile, i managed to write my own, but in php in which i'm more familiar than in js.
I could even calculate the sunrise and sunset. My problem is that i don't know how to get the chart extremes as you did and plot only the necessary.
Is there a way to get these extreme infos in php ?
I will look into your script if i understand it...
Thanks,

Comment: Highcharts is written in pure JavaScript, so it's the only way to get the extremes.

Comment: OK, i will see if i can use all this.
I played a bit with your jsfiddle and got some ideas.
Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Kamil, your answer was very usefull. It works and i'm trying now to make it better with sunrise and sunset. On the same principle, i added a line at midnight.